# Determine whether two circles drawn around two lat/long points with two radii intersect

Tags: intersection, spherical-geometry, geography

I am trying to find a way to check whether two circles drawn around two lat/long points intersect.

For example,

x1 = (lat1 in degree, long1 in degree)

x2 = (lat2 in degree, long2 in degree)

c1 = circle with center x1 and radius 1000 km

c2 = circle with center x2 and radius 1200 km

How do I know whether c1 and c2 intersect? For my requirement, I need to check if they intersect and not find the intersection points themselves. Is there a simple way to determine this? I don't have experience with maths related to geography. Any references?

Comment: The simple way to do this is to use a geodesic library which supports calculations for both problems of geodesy, though all you need here is Inverse (find distance and bearing from two points -- if the sum of the radii distances is less than the actual distance, they intersect)

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @IanTurton Sure, I have completed the tour and will incorporate your feedback in my future questions. Thanks.

Comment: @Vince Thanks, it was very helpful! I made slight modifications to it so that I only get the case where two circles intersect and not the case where one circle is inside another.

If distance < (radius1 + radius2) AND distance + min(radius1, radius2) > max(radius1, radius2) then the two circles intersect.